# How to best translate “The Immolator”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

To immolate means *to sacrifice, especially by the means of fire*.

There is an English noun *immolator*, but *Feueropfernder* doesn’t sound right, and the description *jemand, der ein Feueropfer darbringt* ist not exactly a single-word translation.

Context: I stumbeld upon that word in a criminalistic context, where it was used to describe a person who intends to burn others out of some sort of satanistic beliefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is about the nickname of a criminal (like [der Vampir von Düsseldorf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_K%C3%BCrten) – [the vampire of Düsseldorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_K%C3%BCrten)), a possible German adaption of the name would be ***Feuerteufel.*** I would not go as far as calling it a translation, but a criminal with the features you are describing could be called thusly by German media.

*Feuerteufel* literally translates to *fire devil,* and is usually used to describe arsonists. While it not cover the aspect sacrificing, it does cover using fire and satanism.

Answer (score 4):

A *fire sacrifice* is in German *ein [Brandopfer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Brandopfer)*. (Be careful with setting the right context, because the word can also mean *victim of fire*.) A person that celebrates a religious cult is called *Priester* (same root as the English word *priest*, I assume). So you could call an immolator a *Brandopferpriester*. And actually, there are some rare usages of that word in [ethnological books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brandopferpriester%22&tbm=bks) that can be found on Google Books.

Answer (score 2):

The *priest* is close to the Latin *sacerdos* (one who sacrifices, [1]). The German translation of *Priester* might be not exactly what you want. To emphasize the immolation aspect, you could go for the rarely used "Opferpriester" (Johann Christoph Adelung, [2]).

[1] http://en.catholicpedia.org/wiki/Priest_(disambiguation)

[2] http://www.zeno.org/Adelung-1793/A/Opferpriester,+der